# graphqljs resolver with multiple arguments

Tags: graphql, resolve

I am trying to figure out the best way to write a resolver that filters on multiple arguments.  I have the following graphql type

```
const userQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        Users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(User),
            args: {
                userId: { type: GraphQLString }
            },
            resolve: function (_, { UserId}) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                   //Code to query the data store for the user with the given UserId
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The User type has the following fields

- Name
- UserId
- Type
- Gender

Now if I want to introduce the ability to filter the user based on the name, then what is the best way to do it.  The only way I can think of is to modify the resolver to include the additional args and then based on what is passed in send it to the database.  For example

```
const userQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        Users: {
            type: new GraphQLList(User),
            args: {
                userId: { type: GraphQLString }
            },
            resolve: function (_, { UserId, name}) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                   //Check which argument is passed in and then run the query against the datastore
                })
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Isn't there a better way to do this?  If I want the user to be able to filter on another attribute then it gets more complicated, and the resolve function is going to get huge and complicated.

Comment: have you found any solution?